# Django mardownx not displaying header and blockquotes

Tags: django-forms, markdown

Simple blog in Django (1.11.7  - Python3) in which I have impemented the Markdownx plugin. The plugin works for most of the markdown in preview in my 'edit_article' page, and in the normal view where users can read an article. BUT some of the markup isn't working in either:

Not working:

- blockquotes using `>`
- headers using one or more `#` or `_`
- double-space and carriage return doesn't add a line-break

Links, images, numbered lists, emphasis and bold etc all work.
I posted my markdown in here, but of course it all worked here...

Don't really have any code to post, because most things work, so I'm guessing there isn't any problem with my model/view etc.

Anyone experienced this?

```
# So, let's try a header
```

doesn't work, neither does

```
> this type of blockquote
```

but they shoud produce

## So, lets try a header

and

> this type of blockquote

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to this myself. I am using a CSS framework that resets the styling on the 'broken' markup tags. Until I add back the framework's CSS classes to the H1-H6 tags for example, the reset makes all headers appear as plain text.

So I have to add some custom CSS to the css framework's styling for those tags that are being overridden, or use html in the textarea in the form which should also work.